# Odd home broadband issue

Tags: networking, vpn, broadband

Wondering if anyone can help me, i'm having an odd issue with my home broadband in that I cannot access some sites via a browser - I can however ping them and I get a reply !

I have tried accessing via IP instead, I tried changing my DNS (changed it to Google's), I have obviously tried resetting my router, accessing via different browsers and different devices (Mac, iPad, iPhone and Windows 8 using Chrome, IE and Safari) and I still have the same issue!

I'm lost as to what could be causing it - I am with Plusnet who's support team seem to just read from a script so they are no use! Just keep telling me that there is no issue on the line.

I randomly tried connecting to my work VPN and when connected I can access the sites fine, as soon as I disconnected from the VPN I can no longer access them.

Can anyone suggest anything that might be causing this? It seems odd to me!

Thanks in advane

Comment: The fact that it works when the VPN is up is an indication it is not in your hosts (PC or other devices), but it is either with your ISP or router. Since you factory defaulted router, my money is on your ISP being at fault.

Comment: Can you ping them with `ping -s 1472`? If not, try setting your MTU artificially low, like 1300. If that allows the browser to work, try increasing your MTU until you find where it breaks. If it's a PPPoE issue, it will probably break at 1493. Then set it to the highest value that works.

Comment: 1. Are you using static ip/dns or dhcp at complete level ? 2. If using dhcp is DNS pointing to the router like 192.168.1.1 or isp dns?

Comment: Thanks @SeanClt - I am using DHCP and the DNS is pointing to the router. The router has the DNS configured, this is where i tried changing it to Googles.

Answer (score 1):

[I saw from one of your other comments that my suggestion from an earlier comment worked, so I’m posting it as a real Answer.]

Can you ping them with ping -s 1472? If not, try setting your MTU artificially low, like 1300. If that allows the browser to work, try increasing your MTU until you find where it breaks. If it’s a PPPoE issue, it will probably break at 1493. After you find where it breaks, set it to the highest value that works.

Ideally, your broadband modem/gateway should know what the MTU of the broadband link is, it should limit all traffic it can to that size (a NAT-related feature known as "TCP MSS Clamping"), it should break up oversized packets into smaller pieces that fit (known as "IP datagram fragmentation"), and for clients that want to find the right MTU themselves (known as Path MTU Discovery) it should send them notifications (known as ICMP “Destination Unreachable: Fragmentation Required but ‘Don’t Fragment’ bit set” messages) if they exceed the MTU limit, so the clients can adjust their MTUs themselves. If the modem/gateway from your ISP isn’t doing that, then it’s either misconfigured or buggy. These features have been minimum requirements of broadband modems and home gateways since PPPoE started to catch on around 1999.

If you can’t get your ISP to fix their problematic equipment, then you may have to buy your own high-quality modem or gateway that does it right. In the case of PPPoE over DSL, you can sometimes make your ISP-provided modem act as a simple bridging modem, and have your own home wireless gateway product act as the PPPoE client, which can either learn the correct MTU via the PPPoE handshake, or you can configure its WAN port MTU setting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be that your router is unable to handle DNS requests or is the bottleneck

### Method 1

- Service "DNS Client" : Stop + Disable
- Use Static IP + Static DNS (point to your ISP's DNS instead of google's

### Method 2

- Service "DNS Client" : Stop + Disable
- Update your Router DHCP DNS Settings : Enable DNS Override and use ISP DNS, so that when DHCP hands over IPs it also sets the DNS on the client machine too, which is the ISP DNS instead of the forward all DNS requests to Router

Comment: I reduced the MTU and that fixed it!! The problem now is that I have to do this on a per-device basis which is fine on the laptop but i cannot see a way to set the MTU manually on iPad/iPhone/TV. My broadband provider (Plusnet) told me that they cannot make any changes to the router or service which basically means those devices i cannot edit the MTU won't ever work properly!

Comment: i am not sure how that is helping to hard to comment, please let me know if you tested the suggested methods in answer and the outcome, you can try those in your iPad etc

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Method 1 didn't work and I cannot do Method 2 as I have a router provided by my broadband provider I cannot see any options for DHCP DNS

Comment: please attach model info and screenshots of various pages in question

Comment: The router itself is provided by my broadband provider Plusnet, on the bottom it says the model is 'SAGEMCOM ROUTER 2704N PLUSNET FTTC' - not quite sure how to add a screenshot here so i have uploaded and linked here: http://postimg.org/image/vld59bonj/

Comment: You should be able to find an "Advanced" tab/button on your router GUI and you should be able to lower the MTU from the default (1500 for ADSL)  in the router itself. This will mean each device won't need reconfiguring individually.